# Refresh php script inside an iframe

Tags: php, iframe, refresh

I just want to ask how can I refresh a specific php script inside an iframe. I don't want to refresh the whole iframe because it'll jump into the iframe src, but I want to refresh the script I am currently on to see the changes I applied. Everytime I tried to reload the iframe, it always jumps to the iframe src. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Automatically or if the user clicks a link?

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing an iframe without going to the iframe src? By definition, that's what refreshing is.

Comment: if you can bring more details we will not try to guess what is the problem, as at this point I even didn't understand your question

Comment: I just want to refresh the page where I am currently in. For example, the page in the iframe is page.php, what I want to do is refresh the 'page.php' only if the user clicks a button or just automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iFrame is justs a window that add other page.
Try adding this in the page you want to refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=**linkToRefresh.php**" />
```

In this Exemple you will need to add that line at the botton of your code in the file **linkToRefresh.php**

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)))) One more question, how can I bind this in a `<a href>` code? I have binded it in a submit button. Just wondering if I can do the same to `<a href>`. Thanks! :)))

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question. Do you want to have your link refrest like they get different each X sec and get redirected else where?

Comment: I want to refresh the page when the user clicks a button or a `<a href>` link. Your solution works fine, just want to know if it also works in `<a href>` since I got it working in a button. Well, never mind that. Got it working so thanks! :)))

Comment: Cool, By the way, do not forget to put the word "URL" in caps, as IE does not like it in lower case ;)